# Jquery focus on tab key pressing from a button to another anchor tag is not focusing

Tags: jquery

On pressing tab key i try to focus another anchor tag which is inside in a div tag, which is not focusing, whereas instead of anchor tag if i try with button its working, any suggestion ?

HTML:

```
            <div class="colStyle01">
                <button class="langCountryToggleList" data-bind="click:myLangListViewModel.langCountryToggleList">toggle</button>
            </div>
            <div class="flexColumnStyle01 containerStyle03 errorFormField">
                <div class="flexRowStyle03 langCountryListRightPanel" data-bind="foreach: myLangListViewModel.myCountryListViewModel">
                    <div class="flexColumnStyle05">
                        <span class="chkboxStyle01 chkboxStyle01Normal columnLeft">&nbsp;</span>
                        <a data-bind='html:$data, click: myLangListViewModel.showLanguageList' class="columnLeft"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

From the above HTML, on key press code of button to i try to focus next anchor tag with in the "flexColumnStyle05" div.

JS:

```
               $('.langCountryToggleList').keydown(function (e) {
                    // For keyboard shortcuts of "Tab" pressing 
                    var keycode = e.which;
                    if (keycode == 9) {
                        $(".langCountryListRightPanel").find(".flexColumnStyle05:first").find("a").focusin();
                    }
                    return false;
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.focusin()` should be `.focus()`

Btw, anchors are not inputs, not focusable by default, add attribute `tabindex` to anchor, e.g:

```
<a tabindex="-1" data-bind='html:$data, click: myLangListViewModel.showLanguageList' class="columnLeft"></a>
```

Comment: Wolff: focus() is also not working :( but your another solution of tabindex="-1" is working fine.... thanks a lottt

Comment: @Krish Not sure what you are expecting, here works as i understand it: http://jsfiddle.net/jx5tuhmb/

Comment: Wolff: one more doubt, please look at this fiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/jx5tuhmb/3/ , in this the alert("222"); for the right arrow click script is working only if we have the static content on html, whereas if i have the knockout specific on binding creating html, is not working ? any soln?

Comment: MY HTML:       <div class="flexRowStyle03 langCountryListRightPanel" data-bind="foreach: myLangListViewModel.myCountryListViewModel">
                        <div class="flexColumnStyle05">
                            <span class="chkboxStyle01 chkboxStyle01Normal columnLeft">&nbsp;</span>
                            <a tabindex="-1"  data-bind='html:$data, click: myLangListViewModel.showLanguageList' class="columnLeft"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

Comment: i.e in the above fiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/jx5tuhmb/3/ i am having the static construct of  the row "<div class="flexColumnStyle05">" whereas if i create dynamically using knockout to repeat the construct, than the keyevent for right arrow is not firing :( any help ?